# Mongoose query returning undefined for strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following data in my MongoDB, modeled via my Person model:

```
 { _id: 135, name: 'Alfie', age: 26 }
 { _id: 217, name: 'Ronny', age: 34 }
 { _id: 400, name: 'Sandy', age: 45 }
 { _id: 676, name: 'William', age: 24 }
 { _id: 987, name: 'Debra', age: 31 }
 { _id: 356, name: 'Kevin', age: 47 }
```

Now I run the following query:

```
const findQuery = Person.find({ _id: { $lt: 300 } }).select({ name: 1 })

findQuery.exec().then(doc => {
  for (let person of doc) {
    console.log(person)
    console.log(person._id)
    console.log(person.name)
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
{ _id: 135, name: 'Alfie' }
135
undefined
{ _id: 217, name: 'Ronny' }
217
undefined
```

My question is, why is the string contained within `person.name` return `undefined`? where as the object itself and person._id is returned correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, `name` was missing from mongoose.Schema, so it couldn't find the value, even if it was present in the database.